# Can not change image width and height in Android actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_padding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/icon_switcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="28sp"
            android:layout_height="28sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_person_circle"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/selected"
            android:layout_width="28sp"
            android:layout_height="28sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_selected"/>
    </ImageSwitcher>

    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/contactListTextPrimary"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon_switcher"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:paddingEnd="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:text="Contact title"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/icon_switcher"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="240sp"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
            tools:text="Dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci velit"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make the avatar image smaller. I can do anything but the avatar image fills all the height of the topbar.

This is what I see in Android studio:

[image]

and this is what I see on my phone:

[image]

I have tried different things to make the avatar smaller - adding top/bottom margins, paddings to ImageView, to ImageSwitcher, adding line:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

nothing works. In the mobile phone avatar image always occupies all the height.

Comment: add a padding to your `ImageSwitcher`, for example `android:padding="4dp"`

Comment: Mouaad, I tried it already but it does not give any effect